# Why do I get #2006 MySQL server has gone away and how can I fix this?

Tags: mysql, import, errors, phpmyadmin

What I'm doing is I'm trying to restore MySQL tables from `frm` and `ibd` files. Most of the tables have been restored successfully.
I do it like this:

`mysqlfrm --diagnostic "C:/<path_to_frm>/DB:Users.frm" > "C:/<path_to_sql>/Users.sql"`

`source c:/<path_to_sql>/Users.sql;`

`alter table DB.Users discard tablespace;`

Then I copy the `ibd` file into the MySQL `data` folder and

`alter table DB.Users import tablespace;`

When I go to `PhpMyAdmin` then and click on the imported table I get this error:

> #2006 MySQL server has gone away

Then I restart MySQL and when I'm trying to log in to the `PhpMyAdmin` I get `error 200` and simply can't log in until I drop the table I imported.

I tried changing `max_allowed_packet`, `wait_timeout`, `interactive_timeout` in the `[mysqld]` section of `my.ini`file but it did not help.

I'm very confused and would appreciate any help.

Here's the error log:

> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count
> buffer pool pages
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is
> disabled
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use
> Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib
> 1.2.11
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32
> instructions
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size
> = 128.0M
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of
> buffer pool
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:21 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format
> is Barracuda.
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are
> active.
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.46 started; log sequence
> number 18105434
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] RSA private key file not found:
> C:\MyData\private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] RSA public key file not found:
> C:\MyData\public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*';
> port: 3306
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] IPv6 is available.
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
>
> 2021-06-08 16:26:22 8256 [Note] C:\MySQL\bin\mysqld: ready for
> connections.
>
> Version: '5.6.46'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server
> (GPL)
>
> 2021-06-08 16:27:42 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Sync to disk
>
> 2021-06-08 16:27:42 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Sync to disk - done!
>
> 2021-06-08 16:27:42 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Phase I - Update all pages
>
> 2021-06-08 16:27:42 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Sync to disk
>
> 2021-06-08 16:27:42 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Sync to disk - done!
>
> 2021-06-08 16:27:42 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Phase III - Flush changes to
> disk
>
> 2021-06-08 16:27:42 8256 [Note] InnoDB: Phase IV - Flush complete

Here's the screenshot of what I got in the PhpMyAdmin:

[image]

The structure of the table has been restored but when I click the `Browse` button or click on the table itself the aforementioned error pops up and I can't log in to PhpMyAdmin anymore until I drop the table.

Here's the result of the check:
[image]

Pastebin link to the [full error log](https://pastebin.com/G6xspNnA).

Comment: see manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/check-table.html

Comment: try an repair  "REPAIR TABLE `tbl_name`"

Comment: @nbk I did. It says: _The storage engine for the table doesn't support repair._ The table's storage engine is `InnoDB`, not `MyISAM`.

Comment: @WilsonHauck the link to my error log has been added to the question.

Comment: Apparently corruption exists within indexes for table ab.user.  Primary and other indexes are named as suspect in your error log.  I am not sure how you will correct this trouble, anyone else have a corrective suggestion?  How much data is in your tables?  innodb_buffer_pool_size is default of 128M and likely is too small to be reasonable.  If you could post from your system to pastebin.com  TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; and B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;  we will probably be able to suggest configuration changes to avoid 'server has gone away'.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Here's the link to what you've asked for: [pastebin.com](https://pastebin.com/dZFpJcju)

Comment: @JConstantine  A few questions for you. A) How much RAM on this W64 server? B) How many cores/cpu's? C) Any SSD or NVME devices with data storage? D) Appx # tables in your DB's? E) Appx MB of space used to your data tables/indexes? From DOS command prompt, CD C:\,mydata and DIR will give you reasonable count and space used. Thanks, Analysis in process.

Comment: A) 16 Gb RAM B) AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 B45 Processor 3.00 GHz C) HDDs only D) Not sure what Appx # tables are. My DB consists of InnoDB tables and one MyISAM table. E) Not sure. The estimated amount of space used by my DB is 100 MBs.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions to consider for your instance my.ini [mysqld] section

```
interactive_timeout=7200  # from 300 - seconds of idle tolerance
wait_timeout=7200  # from 90 - seconds of idle tolerance
```

other suggestions you will likely find reasonable for your 16G server

```
thread_cache_size=100  # from 9 to avoid thread creation overhead, when you get busy
innodb_io_capacity=500  # from 200 unless your HDD is 10 years old
log_warnings=2  # from 1 for error log to include aborted connects
innodb_fast_shutdown=0  # from 1 for clean stop and usually avoid recovery on start.
```

Many other tuning suggestions would improve performance when you have more significant number of concurrent connections.